# pass pig arguments via hue (multiquery)

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hue

I am running a pig job from HUE.

On the project I am now I am required to run pig with

```
 pig -no_multiquery
```

Where (and how) do I pass this when using Hue? I can't run this job using multiquery.
Or alternatively, is there a way to switch of multiquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't look hard enough.

```
SET opt.multiquery false;
```

In the pig script itself seems to be running my job as intended.

Comment: You may want to link the associated documentation (and accept your own answer :) )

Comment: You should add a link to the documentation.